# Is there a way in React to update a DOM without constructing Virtual Tree?

Tags: javascript, performance, reactjs

Imagine a list with 100 items. There is a component which displays all of them. Several times per second one (random) item should be moved into a new position. The React native approach would be to rerender whole component by constructing Virtual Tree, then diff it with previous copy, then to patch DOM. The problem is that making a Virtual Tree and creating a diff takes time (about 50ms in my case).

Is there a way in React to skip this creation of Virtual Tree and calculate diff? Like the following: `shouldComponentUpdate` will return `false`; then manually one `Node` will be removed from DOM, and inserted into another position.

**Update**

Concerning to [this video](https://youtu.be/h3KksH8gfcQ?t=28m52s) there is a worst case scenario in React. When you update just one item in a 100 of them. The question is **how to update DOM the fastest possible way** (without diffing 100 items)?

[This is the demo](https://vbarbarosh.github.io/jslib_react_dragdrop_speedy/demo/demo-2-3.html) for the issue, and [this is the code](https://github.com/vbarbarosh/jslib_react_dragdrop_speedy/blob/master/src/static/js/demo/demo-2-3.jsx).

[image: Needle in haystack problem]

Comment: Are you setting the `key` property on the rendered items? That helps React know if it can reuse and just reorder the components it already has.

Comment: @AndersEkdahl: Yep. But the question was *how to completely alleviate creation of Virtual Tree*.

Comment: You're always free to access the DOM node in `componentDidMount` and do what ever DOM manipulation you need. But you should only do that if you're certain that you have a performance issue, since you're essentially working against React.

Comment: Why is it taking 50ms? Have you done any profiling? Have you used the `key` attribute of a component so that React can more easily detect changes among a list of children?

Comment: @WiredPrairie: I've used `componentWillUpdate/console.time()` and `componentDidUpdate/console.timeEnd()`. And *yes I've used `key` properties*, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: Can you provide some code on jsFiddle (or similar) to demonstrate the problem you're having? Otherwise, we're just speculating that it will help in your case.

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using React for this part of your code? You say you don't want a virtual DOM....

Answer (score 1):

You would have to just access the DOM in `componentDidMount`.

But as you are having performance issues. I would try making your children render function "pure". You can use the [PureRenderMixin](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/pure-render-mixin.html) , but as mixins may not be staying around you can

`import shallowEqual from 'react/lib/shallowEqual';`

then in your `shouldComponentUpdate` function do

`shouldComponentUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
   return !shallowEqual(this.props, nextProps) || !shallowEqual(this.state, nextState);
}`

Also look into using [Immutable-JS](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/) for holding your 100 items as a [Map](http://facebook.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) as it will minimise the need to copy or cache your data.

Answer (score 1):

An approach that I have used in one particular case (is not something that could be applied to every case) is to just set some position to every node and then sets its position with CSS.

Something like:

```
<div class="parent">
  <div data-position="3"></div>
  <div data-position="1"></div>
  <div data-position="2"></div>
</div>
```

Although the position attribute changes based on some sorting order, the DOM position of the node remains the same. The problem is that you need to set the visual position of every node with CSS like this:

```
.parent {position: relative}
.parent div {
  position: absolute;
  height: <something>px;
  width: 100%;
}

.parent div[data-position="1"] { top: 0; }
.parent div[data-position="2"] { top: <something>px; }
.parent div[data-position="3"] { top: <something * 2>px; }
```

This saves the browser from performing DOM recalculation, although it needs to recalculate the render tree. But if you change the position of elements several times per second, only one recalculation is made (because the browser will try to apply batch updates as long as you are not performing any [re-layout](http://wilsonpage.co.uk/preventing-layout-thrashing/)).

The CSS 'top' property can be generated either by using a tool like Less/Sass, or with plain JS or can even be generated by the render method in your component, setting the style of each node on each pass: its is only having an pre-set height thats gets multiplied by the index you are iterating.

Sorry if this is not the kind of answer you were expecting, but I used this approach and worked fine for me for hundred of elements.

Comment: Never thought about such approach. Thanks. Unfortunately it work only with absolute positioned elements.

Comment: Yes, but remember that is important to use position: relative in the parent. This way, the parent div can be put anywhere in the markup (and can even be responsive) without any problem. You will have a hard time if for any reason the elements with position absolute need to have a natural height based on its contents (not so easy to achieve with this approach).

Answer (score 0):

One technique is to not recreate nodes that already exist, i.e. caching. Here's a [demo](http://jsbin.com/vugado/3/edit?js,output) with 1,000 nodes and every second there's a random item removed from the array, and an item added at a random position. The update takes 10ms on my laptop with the development version of react.

---

I say this a lot, but I have a large monitor and I can only see 70 of these items at a time and it's too many. The best answer here is to not render 1,000 items from a performance and ux perspective.

---

Say you have an array of objects with an id property, and some other stuff.

```
class Foo {
  constructor(){
    this._nodeCache = {};
  }

  renderItem(item){
    return <div key={item.id}>{item.text}</div>;
  }

  renderOrGetFromCache(id, item){
    if (this._nodeCache[id]) {
      return this._nodeCache[id];
    }
    this._nodeCache[id] = this.renderItem(item);
    return this._nodeCache[id];
  }

  render(){
    return (
      <div>
          {this.props.items.map((item) => this.renderOrGetFromCache(item.id, item))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

So how does this differ from what you were previously doing?

Before the reconciliation looked like:

- render()

  - create a bunch of objects
- for each child

  - compare the key and component type
  - **diff** the attributes
  - **recurse** into children
- perform updates

Now it looks like:

- render()

  - create objects we haven't used before
- for each child

  - compare the key and component type
  - is this the same virtual node (**`===` check**)?

    - if so, we're done
    - otherwise normal reconciliation from above

---

You're still constructing the virtual dom, but we're talking about fractions of a millisecond to render(), and a very fast reconciliation, without even a shallow equals.

---

One more thing to note is the signature of this function:

```
renderOrGetFromCache(id, item)
```

This first parameter takes the place of our shouldComponentUpdate, meaning it needs to uniquely identify a value. If you happen to change the .text property of the object, but the id is the same, it won't update. To fix this, you can change what you pass to renderOrGetFromCache. This way, it'll do the normal diffing of the item rendered because the key is the same, but all other nodes will still be an `===` check.

---

The main trade off here is you need to handle clean up manually. As is, **this code will leak memory**. If an item is no longer rendered, or has changed, it needs to be removed from the _nodeCache. How you do this depends on how your data changes over time, and because this is a performance question, there's no universal 'best' answer.

Comment: Good approach. I thought about it. But I don't like it. I think that it will help not much. I measured time taken  to update (componentWillUpdate....componentDidUpdate) and time taken to render. The former was about 50ms while the latter about 10ms. Event if render will return immediately the whole update would still take about 40ms. Doesn't seems to be a huge improvement.

Comment: When I profile I look at the time code runs for in dev tools. It's hard to measure things accurately in code. Anyway, if you want better perf, render less nodes or do manual dom operations. You can try to squeeze more out of react, but even if react took 0ms, just the dom updates on mobile will be most of a frame; more if there are more items or changes.